# Scrapy distributed connection count

Tags: redis, scrapy, middleware

Let's say I had a couple of servers each running multiple Scrapy spider instances at once. Each spider is limited to 4 concurrent requests with `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS = 4`. For concreteness, let's say there are 10 spider instances at once so I never expect more than 40 requests max at once.

If I need to know at any given time how many concurrent requests are active across all 10 spiders, I might think of storing that integer on a central redis server under some "connection_count" key.

My idea was then to write some downloader middleware that schematically looks like this:

```
class countMW(object):

    def process_request(self, request, spider):
       # Increment the redis key

    def process_response(self, request, response, spider):
        # Decrement the redis key
        return response

    def process_exception(self, request, exception, spider):
        # Decrement the redis key
```

However, with this approach it seems the connection count under the central key, can be more than 40. I even get > 4, for a single spider running (when the network is under load), and even for a single spider when the redis store is just replaced with the approach of storing the count as an attribute on the spider instance itself, to remove any lag in remote redis key server updates being the problem.

My theory for the reason this doesn't work is that even though the request concurrency per spider is capped at 4, Scrapy still creates and queues more than 4 requests in the meantime, and those extra requests call `process_requests` incrementing the count long before they are fetched.

Firstly, is this theory correct?  Secondly, if it is, is there a way that I could increment the redis count only when a true fetch was occurring (when the request becomes active), and decrement it similarly.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion it is better customize scheduler as it fits better to Scrapy architecture and you have full control of the requests emitting process:

> **Scheduler**
>
> The Scheduler receives requests from the engine and enqueues them for feeding them later (also to the engine) when the engine requests them.

https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/architecture.html?highlight=scheduler#component-scheduler

For example you can find some inspiration ideas about how to customize scheduler here: https://github.com/rolando/scrapy-redis

Answer (score 1):

Your theory is partially correct. Usually requests are made much faster than they are fulfilled and the engine will give, not some, but ALL of these requests to the scheduler. But these queued requests are not processed and thus will not call `process_request` until they are fetched.

There is a slight lag between when the scheduler releases a request and when the downloader begins to fetch it; and, this allows for the scenario you observe where more than `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS` requests are active at the same time. Since Scrapy processes requests asynchronously there is this bit of a sloppy double dipping possibility baked in; so, how to deal with it. I'm sure you don't want to run synchronously.

So the question becomes: what is the motivation behind this? Are you just curious about the inner workings of Scrapy? Or do you have some ISP bandwidth cost limitations to deal with, for example? Because we have to define what we really mean by concurrency here.

When does a request become "active"?

- When the scheduler releases it?
- When the downloader begins to fetch it?
- When the underlying Twisted deferred is created?
- When the first TCP packet is sent?
- When the first TCP packet is received?

Perhaps you could add your own scheduler middleware for finer grained control and perhaps can take inspiration from [Downloader.fetch](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/core/downloader/__init__.py#L98).

Comment: Thanks. As for the motivation: I have a pool of proxies and I want to limit the total connections made simultaneously (across multiple servers, celery threads each running a spider instance).